# Access bitbucket file directly via component

Tags: angular, bitbucket

I trying to access a changelog file inside an angular component, directly from a bitbucket URL

```
https://bitbucket.xxx.com/projects/xxx/repos/xxx/browse/CHANGELOG.md
```

But when i tried to access, it keeps asking me to login.

How do I authenticate the bitbucket url, so that i could directly access the content of the file inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bitbucket Server REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/example-basic-authentication/) with simple basic auth. However that means you either need to ask your application user for his bitbucket login / password in order to authenticate or hardcode the credentials to your bitbucket account in the code that is going to be visible to everybody who is able to use the browser console.

So, the whole approach is not good.

What you can do instead:

1. Give your users URL to your bitbucket and that's their problem to login there
2. Bundle the changelog into your application and have it as is on your server -> no problem with authentication but needs to be configured
3. Use some proxy backend method that asks for changelog and returns it to you without additional authentication